# Could not access file: C:\wamp\tmp\file.tmp

Tags: php, phpmailer

PHP script :

```
    <?php

require_once '../lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

function clean_string($string) {
$bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
}

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED
    //$email_to = "hidden";
    //$email_subject = "Request for Portfolio check up from ".$first_name." ".$last_name;

    $title = array('Geslacht', 'Meneer', 'Mevrouw');
    $selected_key = $_POST['title'];
    $selected_val = $title[$_POST['title']]; 

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

     $email_message = "";
    $email_message .="Title: ".$selected_val."\n";
    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";

    $allowedExts = array("doc", "docx", "pdf", "PDF");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/pdf")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/msword"))

&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "<script>alert('Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] ."')</script>";
    }
  else
    {
        $d='C:/wamp/www//upload/';
        $de=$d . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $de)) {

       echo "<script>alert('File Uploaded')</script>"; 
    }else {

         echo "<script>alert('File not Uploaded')</script>";
    };
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $filePath = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
     //add only if the file is an upload
     }
  }
else
  {
  echo "<script>alert('Not PDF or Word File!!')</script>";
  }

    echo "<script>alert('Mail being created...')</script>";



// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
//Create a new PHPMailer instance
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Host = 'send.one.com';
$mail->Port = 465;
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username ='';
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password   = '';
//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $first_name.' '.$last_name);
//Set an alternative reply-to address
//$mail->AddReplyTo('replyto@example.com','First Last');
//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->AddAddress(', 'Bora Urfali');
$mail->Subject = "Sollicitatie van $first_name ";

$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
//Send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "<script>alert('Something went wrong! Please try again!')</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>alert('Mail Send!')</script>";

}
}
```

The file I have uploaded is comming in this directory :

```
C:\wamp\www\upload\
```

Still I'm getting the error it could not acces the file in this directory:

```
C:\wamp\tmp\file.tmp
```

error is : Could not access file: C:\wamp\tmp\phpF6A9.tmp

Question:

Why doesn't it search for the file at the correct directory ?

Comment: what's your exact error? please copy it verbatim. we're not here to guess.

Comment: error is 'Could not access file: C:\wamp\tmp\phpF6A9.tmp'. This directory does exist. But ofcourse the file is not there...I don't understand. I'm using Wamp server btw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Near the end of the script you add `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name']` as an attachment

```
$mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

but the file is not there any more because you moved it from there 30 lines before:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $de)) {
```

You should:

```
$mail->AddAttachment($de, $_FILES['file']['name']);
```

but you should also check if the file was uploaded and successfully moved, before attaching it.